# Is it possible to append the item quantity on Select Option at Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my Select Option:-

```html
<select id="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control">
    <option>Carrot - 3</option>
    <option>Cucumber - 2</option>
</select>
```

I want to append the quantity of the item, if the same item added.
For the example:

If I add 1 more carrot, the option should be change from:-

```
<option>Carrot - 3</option> to be <option>Carrot - 4</option>
```

Can I use javascript for this? if not, how I can do it?

Comment: how do you add items?

Comment: For the first question, yes you can do that, the second is to broad without showing what you have tried so far

Comment: Google `javascript change option text in select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

```js
$("#addOption").on("click", function(e){
    var newOption = $("#optionText").val();
    var options = {};
    var index = 0;
    $("#listboxstock option").each(function() {
      debugger;
      var valueComponents = $(this).val().split(" - ");
      if (valueComponents[0] == newOption) {
        var number = parseInt(valueComponents[1]);
        number++;
        $(this).val(valueComponents[0] + " - " + number);
      }
      options["option" + index] = $(this).val();
      index++;
    });
    var $el = $("#listboxstock");
    $el.find('option')
      .remove()
      .end();
    //console.log($el);
    $.each(options, function(key,value) {
      $el.append($("<option>" + value + "</option>"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control">
    <option>Carrot - 3</option>
    <option>Cucumber - 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type the name of the item to add" id="optionText" />
<button id="addOption">Add Option</button>
```

Comment: that was exactly what i want... thanks so much dude :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `replace` on the `textContent` of the selected `option` element, using a regular expression to extract the number part, and then use the callback function of the `replace` to inject the updated number.

Here is a demo:

```js
function adjustCount(diff) {
    var sel = document.getElementById('listboxstock');
    if (sel.selectedIndex < 0) return; // nothing selected
    var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
    opt.textContent = opt.textContent.replace(/\d+/, function (m) {
        return Math.max(0, +m + diff); // adjust, but not below 0
    });
}

document.getElementById('inc').addEventListener('click', adjustCount.bind(null, 1));
document.getElementById('dec').addEventListener('click', adjustCount.bind(null, -1));
```

```html
<select id="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control">
    <option>Carrot - 3</option>
    <option>Cucumber - 2</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="inc">Add</button>
<button id="dec">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can use a multitude of built-in functions to do that. Personally I would use split and parseInt creating the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<select size="5">
<option onclick="myFucntion()" id="item">Carrot - 3</option>
<option>Cucumber - 2</option>
</select>
<script>
function myFucntion(){
    var str=document.getElementById("item").innerHTML;
    str=str.split(" ");
    res=parseInt(str[2]);
    res++;
    document.getElementById("item").innerHTML="Carrot - "+res;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure I understood what you wanted to do but i believe you wanted this.